# How can I effectively deal with an incorporeal enemy as an alchemist? Are alchemist's bombs considered magical?

Tags: magic, pathfinder-2e, alchemist, incorporeal

Incorporeal enemies have double resistances against non-magical damage. Many other creatures also have resistances against some non-magical damage but incorporeal creatures are the biggest offenders.

Are alchemist's bombs considered magical? If not how can I make them count as magical other than with Celestial Strikes or Fiendish Strikes which are both very high level and would lock me into either Aasimar or Tiefling?

It feels like someone completely forgot about Alchemist with these resistances because unless I'm wrong all other classes deal magical damage because of spells or magical weapons.

EDIT: Another option I found is the Sprite ancestry which has Magical Strikes as a built-in ability.

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but [Spirit Strikes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1374) from Duskwalker and [Enforced Order](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2293) from Aasimar are similar feats to the two you mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

## Bombs are *not magical*, but you do not really need that

If you do not have a Ghost Charge or other special bomb, the incorporeal creature indeed has double resistance.

If you play the Wraith apocalypse in a CRB only game, do *not* bring an Alchemist.

### [Ghost Charge](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=687) against undead

Most incorporeal creatures are undead, usually easy to recognize. Positive damage works fine against them.

### Other incorporeal creatures

There are a few [non-undead](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=1146), but all of them have things they are not resistant to beside *force*. Alchemists have high Int, so can have many skills at least trained. A Recall Knowledge check can help you identify these.

Comment: They also have [Lodestone Bombs](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1904) at higher levels. Ghost Charge is still almost certainly better (as incorporeal and using metal weapons has very little overlap) but this will help against the 3 creatures that are incorporeal and don't have their resistance bypassed by positive (so far as I can find).

Comment: I feel like this answer is for a different question, rather than directly addressing the problem raised. What if the Alchemist doesn't have Ghost Charges (or the formula), and so HAS to use another type of bomb?

Comment: @YogoZuno, you are right, edited

Answer (score 3):

Bombs are items with the [Alchemical](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=6) trait, which says, in part

> Alchemical items aren’t magical and don’t radiate a magical aura.

Therefore, against an incorporeal foe, most bombs will be resisted by double the normal resist all damage. Exceptions would be any bombs dealing Force or Positive damage, or that otherwise specify they damage incorporeal enemies, like the [Ghost Charge](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=687).